# Mobile push message in not getting delivered

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, mobilesdk, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios

I am trying to send mobile push through app in marketing cloud, however it is being delivered. It says it has been send however the send count is zero. I have implemented mobile push SDK in the application and data is coming fine in all contacts in marketing cloud. However when I create filtered list and try to send the mobile push message it is not getting delivered. I have tried to send push message to "clever tap" and it worked fine it is being delivered.

Support team said that there is API key mismatch which should not be the case because it is working with clever tap.

Plesae suggest. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have more than 1 push provider included in your application?  When creating your audience list in the Marketing Cloud how many contacts are shown in the audience list count?  What do the SDK logs say? Troubleshooting steps: http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/trouble-shooting/trouble-shooting-push-setup.html